# Trianlge area and minimum value using Mathematica.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, mathematica

A triangle has two of its corners in (3.052 , 0 , 1.456), (0 , 3.052, 1.456), and the third of the curve in the room consisting of all points (3.052 , 3.052, a ^ 2 + 1.456), where a is a real number. Calculate the area  f(a) of the triangle and state where the function assumes its minimum value. (Positive oriented ON system.)
The area can be expressed as a function.

How i tried using mathematica.

u1 = {3.052, 0, 1.456}

u2 = {0, 3.052, 1.456}

u3 = {3.052, 3.052, a^2 + 1.456}

v1 = u2 - u1

v2 = u3 - u1

Norm[Cross[v1, v2]/2]

Which gives the area: Sqrt[21.690927651904005`+ 1/2 Abs[0.` + 3.052` a^2]^2]

And using the Minimize function: Minimize[Sqrt[21.690927651904005`+ 1/2 Abs[0.` + 3.052` a^2]^2], a]

gives the minimum value for a = 5.87669*10^-7

This is wrong or is in the wrong form, would appreciate any help!

Comment: It seems to me that, in the description of the triangle, you are using the comma for two distinct things.

Comment: Thanks! edited it!

Comment: Your curve is a straight line and the problem can then be solved without calculus: the minimum is for $a=0$.

Comment: By the way: if you want an EXACT result in Mathematica you must avoid using real numbers. Try substituting $3.052$ with $3052/1000$, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 3.052=p and 1.456=q, so the points are (say) A$(p,0,q)$; B$(0,p,q)$ and C$(p,p,a^2+q)$

Now, $\vec {AB}=(-p,p,0)$ and $\vec {BC}=(p,0,a^2)$

$$\vec {AB} \times \vec {BC}=(a^2p,a^2p,-p^2)$$

Area=$\frac{1}{2}|\vec {AB} \times \vec {BC}|=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2a^4p^2+p^4}=\frac{1}{2}p \sqrt{2a^4+p^2}$

$\frac{dA}{da}=\frac{2pa^3}{\sqrt{2a^4+p^2}}=0 \Rightarrow a=0$

Comment: Thanks! it was a messy problem with all these integers